# Make ffmpeg loop video indefinitely while streaming

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp

Is it possible to make `ffmpeg` loop an input file infinite times copying its video and audio and streaming it to a RTMP server (nginx with rtmp module).

I am trying to create an animated video which repeats on the RTMP server for as long as the `ffmpeg` instance is running.

I have found the concat demuxer, but all examples I've found is using a playlist to concat the same video over and over into a single video. While I could create a stupidly long video that no sane user would watch in its entirety, it would consume a lot of disk space and wouldn't make sense to do in the least.

I could also add a `while true` bash loop to restart the process, but this may introduce delays or disconnects into the stream.

I am simply trying to find a way to take a single video and restream it once it ends without delays/interruptions in the stream.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i input {-rest of your parameters} -f flv rtmp://output
```

Comment: Doesn't work when the input is a stream, e.g. `.m3u8`

Comment: `-stream_loop -1` being at the beginning is important here